# Derivation of electric field intensity for Line charge

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: Evaluation of Electric field due to line Charge]

[image: Derivation]

These snapshot is taken from Principle of Electromagnetics by Matthew N.O. Sadiku.

In this derivation I don't understand the highlighted step. In previous step we are defining a position vector **R** from element **dl** to point in space (*x,y,z*) which is equal to x**ax** + y**ay** + (z-z')**az** , this position vector is defined for a unique point.

However in the next step we are defining same position vector in cylindrical coordinate but we are defining only two cylindrical coordinate and \$ \phi \$ coordinate is missing. I know that Electric field intensity will be constant for all values of \$ \phi \$ for a given value of z. But I think position vector should be directed toward a unique point in space. Can anyone justify why we are not defining \$ \phi \$ in the highlighted step?

Comment: R is regarded as a vector so you can think that as two element(low part and z part) of R vector.

Answer (score 1):

In the highlighted area vector **R** is the place translation from a charge element dl in z axis to the observation point where the total **E** is wanted.

The first term of **R** is the placement of the xy projection of the observation point (a constant vector in xy plane when the integration is done), the second term is the z component of **R**, it's the z-difference times z-unit vector. The second term contains the integration variable (=the z coordinate of the charge element).

ϕ is constant in integration, it is included to xy-place of the observation point (ϕ=the direction angle of unit vector **a**p), but it isn't needed as variable in the integration, where only a zone in z axis is walked through to collect total **E**